# Disable a jButton Conditionally

Tags: java, string, swing, jbutton, string-comparison

I have a jTable that containing some accounts data. I want to disable a button when i click on jTable Row, if the cell text(Data) is "NO" of column number 4 (in code vise column 3). Below is my code, but it does not work.

```
int selectedRow = tblJournalBatchList.getSelectedRow();
if (tblJournalBatchList.getValueAt(selectedRow, 3) == "NO") {
    btnPost.setEnabled(false);
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it code of `SelectionListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.equals` instead `==`. you can't use `==` for this case as `String` is a `object` type.it only works for primitives like int,char....you are checking reference quality that's why it's not work. for more information see this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
int selectedRow = tblJournalBatchList.getSelectedRow();

if ((String)tblJournalBatchList.getValueAt(selectedRow, 3).equals("NO")) {

    btnPost.setEnabled(false);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Dude, It worked. But no need to cast to String value as it's already a string value. am I correct?

Comment: nice don't forget to read the referenced question

Comment: note required wrapping `if ((String)tblJournalBatchLis....` into `if (selectedRow > -1) {` to trest if any row is selected, btw remove all code and replace with description and link to tutorial about `ListSelectionListener`